# How to Skip Translation for specific input in magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4.3, translate, i18n

I have added quantity increment and decrement button in minicart

```
<input data-bind="value: qty, attr: {
                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       'data-item-qty': qty,
                       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                       }"
                       type="number"
                       size="4"
                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
```

But when store switched from English to Arabic value within input also translated to Arabic counting how can i stop or prevent this transation.